# Golang пакет time возвращение времени на русском

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте, подскажите как правильно реализовать дату и время на русском в go?

Comment: Можете использовать библиотеку **Russian-Time** by ivahaev<br>
Подробно: [Тут](https://github.com/ivahaev/russian-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дата и время на русском это с месяцами/днями недели словами или просто в привычном формате?

Если просто в ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ:СС, то можно так

`fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("02.01.2006 15:04:05"))`

В отличие от php, c и т.п. в стандартном пакете Go символы форматирования это не буквы со спец-символами, а образцы.
Например 02 это день месяца с ведущим нулём, 01 - номер месяца с ведущим нулём. Просто 2 это день месяца без ведущего нуля и т.п.
В результате формат времени выглядит как представление даты 
2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00 в том формате как вам нужно.

Образцы можно посмотреть в константах пакета time https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Comment: 01 - месяц, 02 - день, 03(15) - час, 04 - минута, 05 - секунда, (20)06 - год, (-/+)07(:00) - зона. Вот шпаргалка: `Mon Jan 2 03:04:05PM 2006 -0700`